# Braintree node.js w/ iOS 9 Swift 2.1 - client token error

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, paypal, braintree

I'm attempting to setup a relatively simple Braintree server running on node.js with my client written in Swift 2.1 for iOS 9, and while I'm able to log the client token, I'm getting the following error:

`[BraintreeSDK] ERROR Unsupported client token version. Please ensure your server is generating a valid Braintree ClientToken with a server-side SDK that is compatible with this version of Braintree iOS.`

Below is my server code (which was adapted from a BraintreeDev repository):

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var braintree = require('braintree');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var parseUrlEnconded = bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
});

var gateway = braintree.connect({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  publicKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  privateKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Creates a new token and returns it in the response.
app.get('/token', function (req, res) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (error, response) {
    res.json(response);
  });
});

app.post('/payment', function (req, res) {
  var sale = {
    amount: "10",
    payment_method_nonce: req.param('payment_method_nonce')
  };

  gateway.transaction.sale(sale, function (error, response) {
    if (!error && response.success) {
      res.json(response);
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  });
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)

module.exports = app;
```

And here is my iOS code:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var braintreeClient: BTAPIClient?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let clientTokenURL = NSURL(string: "https://my-heroku-app.herokuapp.com/token")!
        let clientTokenRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: clientTokenURL)
        clientTokenRequest.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(clientTokenRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            let clientToken = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Client Token: \(clientToken)")
            self.braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: clientToken!)
            print(response?.description)

        }.resume()
    }
...
```

This seems like something that should be very straight forward, and I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting this error.

EDIT:  I am using the most recent version of the Braintree SDK for iOS and the most recent version of the Braintree node.js package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

It appears that you are serializing the entire response from `gateway.clientToken.generate` and passing it to the `BTAPIClient`. You should remove the `clientToken` from the response object and only pass the clientToken string value to `BTAPIClient`.

```
app.get('/token', function (req, res) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (error, response) {
    res.json(response.clientToken);
  });
});
```

See the [clientToken.generate](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/node) documentation for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am now getting the following error: `[BraintreeSDK] ERROR Invalid client token. Please ensure your server is generating a valid Braintree ClientToken.`

Comment: And also this error: `ERROR BTClient could not initialize because the provided clientToken was invalid`

Comment: Please reach out to our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for more help troubleshooting your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above solved my issue with the server-side code.  However, I was still getting an error in the iOS application:

`ERROR BTClient could not initialize because the provided clientToken was invalid`

I am now using Alamofire, and my function is as follows:

```
associatedType ClientTokenResult = (clientToken: String?) -> ()

func fetchToken(completion: ClientTokenResult) {
    let parameters = [String: AnyObject]()
    Alamofire.request(Router.Get("api/token", parameters))
        .validate()
        .response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(clientToken: nil)
            } else {
                let clientToken = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                // NOTE: This shouldn't be necessary, but as of right now the server is returning the token
                // with quotation marks.
                let strippedClientToken = clientToken.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"",
                    withString: "")

                print("Client Token: \(strippedClientToken)")
                print(response?.debugDescription)

                completion(clientToken: strippedClientToken)
            }
    }
}
```

**Update:** You can see in my `NOTE` comment that the issue is that my server is returning the token with quotation marks (I've yet to figure out why) so I had to "strip them" from the token.  All is working well now.